# SQL - check if unique value is found in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a base table with one million customer numbers, just one column. Now I want to add a second column with the values '1' and '0' if the customers are found in another specific table.

Base table:

```
select relationNr
from Relation
```

Second table:

```
select relationNr
from Contract
where startdate < '01-01-2019'
    and enddate is null
    and type = 'donor'
```

I expect two columns, the first with all relationnumbers and the second with a 1 or 0 if, depending whether it's present in the second table or not.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output!

Comment: You're asking for data inconsistency. At least use triggers to manage that new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an outer join for that:

```
select r.relationnr, 
       case 
          when c.relationnr is not null then 1
          else 0
        end as is_present
from relation r
  left join (
    select relationNr
    from Contract
    where startdate < '01-01-2019'
      and enddate is null
      and type = 'donor' 
  ) c on c.relationnr = r.relationnr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **LEFT JOIN** to achieve your result:

```
SELECT
    relationNr
    ,IIF(c.relationnr IS NOT NULL,1,0) is_present
FROM
    Relation r
    LEFT JOIN Contract c ON r.relationnr = c.relationnr
        AND c.startdate < '01-01-2019'
        AND c.enddate is null
        AND c.type = 'donor'
```